# How to allow Apache server external access

Tags: php, html, apache, web-services, ssh

I have various PIs running daemon services that start automatically on boot. I'm trying to set up a web page to monitor the status of each daemon service. For this I have come up with following PHP script:

```
<?php //dashboard.php
$command = "ssh -p 97 -i PI12.rsa pi@192.xxx.xx.xx tail -5 
/var/log/vidlog.csv ; sudo service surround status ";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>$output</pre> ";
?>
```

This script sits on my CMS server, which is the same server that I use to connect to my PIs (via SSH). The script runs when executed from the command line so I know the script works, however my web browser displays a blank page. I'm using the Apache web service host which I installed with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I'm assuming the problem is that my Apache server does not have access to my PI? What do I need to do to allow my Apache web server and PI to interact?

Comment: What is a PI? (besides 3.141592…)

Comment: After installing the Apache web server, you'll have to configure which files should be public and how to treat those. Please start at some Apache documentation examples. e.g. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html As it is this question is much too broad as we will have to start to teach you the very basics of web server administration.

Comment: I was referring to a Raspberry Pi! I'm trying to use a PHP script to pull the log file and the cron service status from the PI and display the content onto my web page.

Comment: Currently my apache2.conf file has the following:

 `<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown us won't run at all - it has syntax errors. I think you're missing a double quote char after `sudo service surround status`

There's no path on the identity file - please tell me you didn't leave that inside your document root?

Using shell_exec to invoke a shell command is a very crude tool. You really want to see the return status and the stderr. While you could address the latter with IO redirection, you'd be better using proc_open() to solve both.

Note that ssh (like many Unix/Linux commands) has a -v option for debugging, and PHP has a very good ssh extension.

Comment: My question was how to allow Apache server access to files/ folders on a Raspberry PI. Below is my temporary solution to this problem. I'm not familiar with proc_open() but I will look into it.

Comment: There's no reason to think the server does not have access - if your solution addresses this, then the server ALREADY had access - but the user it was running as did not.

Comment: "but the user it was running as did not" which is the same conclusion I reached in my solution..

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the www-data user not having the right privileges to SSH onto the PI.

So I found the solution by going into **/etc/apache2/envvars** and changing the www-data user to a user that has access to the PIs:

```
 export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
 export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

to:

```
 export APACHE_RUN_USER=myuser
 export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=myuser
```